# Fire slid event on init of bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wan to fire `slid` event of bootstrap carousel at carousel initialization.

I wan to run a function on `slid` event

```
$('#carousel').on('slid', function () {
// do something…
})
```

The above code is working well, but when carousel init then its first carousel item dont fire `slid`.

Please tell me how fire `slid` on carousel init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function to fire the `slid` event after you initialize your carousel:

```
$('#carousel').carousel();
$('#carousel').on('slid', function () {
    // do something…
})
$('#carousel').trigger('slid');
```

**[Working Demo](http://bootply.com/73597)**